# MonoTouch Dialog. StyledStringElement's Height

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Is it possible to change the Element's height somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement `IElementSizing`

```
public interface IElementSizing {
    float GetHeight (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath);
}
```

Look at `MultilineElement` or `StyledMultilineElement` for examples.

Comment: Does it provide changing the height, not just getting the current?

Comment: If you implement the interface then MT.D will call your method to **set** the height to the value you returned.

Comment: it means that I actually have to create a new class based either on MultilineElement or StyledMultilineElement. Is there any way to do it directly without need of a class?

Comment: Not quite, you need a new class that **implements** `IElementSizing`. Of course inheriting from *MultilineElement is one way to do so. I don't know any simpler, more direct way, to do it. OTOH I found defining my own Element-based types to be very useful for other kinds of customization (styles, actions...)

Comment: You can subclass any existing Element-type and implement the IElementSizing interface.